# separate Docker image from each services present in qcow2

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

I would like to have multiple Docker containers - each for one services in a Kubernetes POD. Currenly, i have qcow2 images. With guestmount command, i am able generate the tar file from the qcow2 images and create docker image with the tar file.

*$ guestmount -a ~/image.qcow2 -i /mnt/convert 
$ tar -cvzf ~/image.tar.gz -C /mnt/convert ./*

But the docker image contains all the services present in that qcow2.

It will be too much time consuming to write separate docker file for each services manually, as there are too many docker files to create.

Is there any tool available which will generate the separate docker images for each services present in the qcow2 image.

Answer (score 0):

Do all the containers in the pod need to be running at the same time? It's usually good practice, to separate out the containers into separate pods with corresponding services.

If you wanted to keep the same container, you could model after hyperkube and have each pod start the correct service based upon entrypoint, however, I would rather take on the multiple dockerfiles to keep apps seperate and deal with that complexeity vs the latter.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.But my question was is there any tool which will generate the docker files or docker images from the services present in a qcow2 images. I would like to avoid manually writing the docker files.